# firefox displays text while form input value is empty

Tags: forms, html, firefox

Hi, I'm making a website and with a form but firefox keeps displaying unwanted text in the input fields when its value is empty.
This happens when using email or tel in the input method.

```
        <form action='locatie.php?root=<?php echo $root; ?>' target='_self' method='post' onSubmit='return checkForm()' >
<table style='width:725px;' id='text' border='1'>
  <tr>
    <td colspan='7'></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan='7' ><hr /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style='width:100px;' ><label for='locatie' >Locatie naam: </label></td>
    <td style='width:140px;' ><input type='text' name='locatie' id='locatie' value='' placeholder='locatie naam' maxlength='20' size='20' /></td>
    <td style='width:8 0px;' ><label for='adres' >Adres: </label></td>
    <td colspan='4'><input type='text' name='adres' id='adres' value='' placeholder='Adres locatie' maxlength='30' size='30'/></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><label for='beheer' >Beheerder: </label></td>
    <td ><input type='text' name='beheer' id='beheer' value='' placeholder='Beheerder naam' maxlength='21' size='20' /></td>
    <td><label for='tel' >Tel nr: </label></td>
    <td style='width:140;' ><input type='text' name='tel' id='tel' value='' maxlength='13' size='12' /></td>
    <td style='width:80px;' >Email:</td>
    <td colspan='2'><input type='text' name='email' id='email' value=' ' placeholder='Email beheer' maxlength='31' size='20' /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style='vertical-align:top;' ><label for='route' >Route beschrijving: </label></td>
    <td style='vertical-align:top;' colspan='6'><textarea name='route' id='route' value='' placeholder='Google maps link met route' cols='75' rows='10' ></textarea></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan='7'>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td ><label for='ondergrond' >Ondergrond: </label></td>
    <td ><select name='ondergrond' id='ondergrond' >
                <option value='Veld' >Veld</option>
          <option value='Zaal' >Zaal</option>
          <option value='Kunstgras' >Kunstgras</option>
         </select>
     </td>
    <td><label for='seizoen' >Seizoen: </label></td>
    <td><select name='seizoen' id='seizoen' >
                <option value='Veld' >Veld</option>
          <option value='Zaal' >Zaal</option>
         </select>
    </td>
    <td colspan='3'></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan='7'><input type='submit' name='action' id='action' value='Opslaan' /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan='7'><hr /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</form>
```

In firefox, the input field will contain the text "Enter your phone number here" or "Enter your email here" which I dont want .
Is there any way to prevent firefox from doing this except for adding content to the input?

If added the whole form, the rest of the page contains a lot of php that just saves the form to a database.

Comment: please post your more html code

Answer (score 2):

You're setting the `placeholder` attribute on the `<input>` field, whose purpose it is to show something as long as no data is entered.

Just remove that attribute and you'll be fine.

Citing from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/Input):

> **placeholder**
>
> A hint to the user of what can be entered in the control . The placeholder text must not contain carriage returns or line-feeds. This attribute applies when the value of the type attribute is text, search, tel, url or email; otherwise it is ignored.

Comment: This sounds logical, but his `placeholder` doesn't contain the text  "Enter your phone number here"; instead it contains " nr beheer".

Comment: @feeela From the code given it's the only source of text inside the input field. The string in `placeholder` actually looks kind of messed up, so I assumed it's not the original text.

Comment: @Maurits Based on that information I assume that there **must** exist some sort of value. Maybe the value is set by some JavaScript – but for sure not through Firefox itself.

Comment: if opend the side in Chrome and IE also but there it doesn't happen.
i also check the Javascript i'm using but nothing there either.

Comment: @Maurits can you put up a fiddle containing more code (the whole site) so we can have a look at more of the code?

Answer (score 1):

The Placeholder is the problem but the solution is not to remove it. Use  autocomplete="off" inside the input tag.

Comment: Autocomplete allows the browser to supply a value based on past entries if the browser is configured to do so. It doesn't affect the behavior that is being asked about this this question.

Answer (score 0):

Clear your cookies, saved form data and browser cache. Also disable JS to see if this is the culprit.

You might also want to remove the placeholder="" attribute if you're not using it anyway.

I strongly recommend you download the "web developer toolbar" by Chris Pederick, because clearing all of this from your browser and disabling JS / CSS etc is as easy as the click of a button. Available for both Firefox and Chrome.

http://chrispederick.com/work/web-developer/

Good luck, Michael.

Comment: Thx for the advise i already have the plugin and tried it.
didn't solve the problem i think I'll just make a javascript that checks the form for those 2 lines and removes them. leaving a clean input field.

Answer (score 0):

Posting this here because this is the SO issue I found and, while it may not apply to OP's situation it did help me.

Firefox (and similarly Safari) has a bug where non-numeric characters are rendered in the `input` field although the `value` of the input remains empty.

To work around this I check the browser being used via this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/26358856/6410635 - and then set the element type to `"text"` instead of `"number"` and then adding a `pattern` attribute of `"\d*"` to the input.

```
<input
  type={safari || firefox ? "text" : "number"}
  pattern="\d*"
  ...
/>
```

Firefox bug:
https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1398528